# Can't change image size or left-margin no matter what code I change React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add a left-margin to the logo by 50px and to enlarge it, but no matter what I do I cannot make any of the changes i'm looking to make, nothing I change edit's the size or margin of the image I'm working with. I have the current code i'm working with and the figma example, is there anyone with experience solving this problem? (Image is a SVG)

Figma example link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXGiA.jpg

Current website link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sryy7.jpg

Code 1(header.jsx):

```html
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import { useGoogleLogin, useGoogleLogout } from 'react-google-login';
import ShortID from 'shortid';
import { setIsLoggedIn } from '../../../redux/actions/pagebuilder';
import { AuthContext } from '../../../components/AuthContext/AuthContext';
import * as S from './Header.style';
import { customStyles } from './Header.style';
import { apiDomain, fp } from '../../../config';
import Link from '../../../components/Link';
import UserLogin from '../../../components/UserLogin';
import RegisterModal from '../../../components/RegisterModal';
import LogoImg from '../../../assets/images/logologo.png';

const navLinks = [
  {
    text: 'Learning',
    to: '/learning-center',
    color: 'primary',
  },
  {
    text: 'About',
    to: '/about',
    color: 'primary',
  },
  {
    text: 'Contact',
    to: '/contact',
    color: 'primary',
  },
];

function Header() {
  const [user, setUser] = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [modalIsOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [loginModalIsOpen, setLoginModalIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [companyHash, setCompanyHash] = useState('');
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies(['atomic_session']);
  // stored cookie hash and expiration date
  let cookieHash = '';
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  const [cookieExpirationDate, setCookieExpirationDate] = useState(
    new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 2)),
  );
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  // Bind modal to the appElement
  Modal.setAppElement('#root');

  function googleLoginApiResponseHandler(response) {
    if (response === 'USER_NOT_FOUND') {
      console.log('Not yet registered.');
    } else {
      console.log('Login Successful');
      console.log(response.USER_SESSION_HASH);
      cookieHash = response.USER_SESSION_HASH;
      setCookie('atomic_session', cookieHash, {
        path: '/',
        expires: cookieExpirationDate,
        sameSite: 'Strict',
      });
      // We are TEMPORARILY setting isAuth to false, which is NOT normal, for the developers to have faster access to the projects page during the development. This must be turned back to true before the deployment.
      setUser((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, isAuth: true }));
      dispatch(setIsLoggedIn(true));
    }
  }

  const onSuccess = (res) => {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        command: 'login_with_google',
        fp,
        email: res.profileObj.email,
        access_token: res.accessToken,
      }),
    };
    fetch(`${apiDomain}/user.php`, requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => googleLoginApiResponseHandler(data))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  const onLogoutSuccess = (res) => {
    dispatch(setIsLoggedIn(false));
    setUser((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, isAuth: false }));
  };

  const onFailure = (res) => {
    if (res) {
      console.log(res);
    }
    return null;
  };

  const { signIn } = useGoogleLogin({
    onSuccess,
    onFailure,
    clientId:
      '523964094560-utcl46ugtmcl8p3nfi7s68bc7pplcio4.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    cookiePolicy: 'single_host_origin',
    isSignedIn: true,
  });

  const { signOut } = useGoogleLogout({
    onLogoutSuccess,
    onFailure,
    clientId:
      '523964094560-utcl46ugtmcl8p3nfi7s68bc7pplcio4.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    cookiePolicy: 'single_host_origin',
  });

  const logout = () => {
    removeCookie('atomic_session');
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    setUser((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, isAuth: false }));
    signOut();
  };

  function openLoginModal() {
    setLoginModalIsOpen(true);
  }

  function closeLoginModal() {
    setLoginModalIsOpen(false);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user.isAuth === true) {
      navigate('/projects-main/all-projects');
    }
  }, [user, cookies]);

  useEffect(() => {
    signIn();
    const { search } = window.location;
    const params = new URLSearchParams(search);
    const registration = params.get('registration');
    if (registration) {
      setIsOpen(true);
      setCompanyHash(registration);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <S.HeaderWrapper>
      <Link to={user.isAuth ? '/projects-main/all-projects' : '/'}>
        <S.Logo src={LogoImg} alt="Logo" />
      </Link>
      <S.NavBar>
        {navLinks.map((link) => (
          <Link key={ShortID.generate()} to={link.to} color={link.color}>
            {link.text}
          </Link>
        ))}
        {user.isAuth ? (
          <S.NavButton color="primary" onClick={() => logout()}>
            Logout
          </S.NavButton>
        ) : (
          <S.NavButton color="primary" onClick={openLoginModal}>
            Login
          </S.NavButton>
        )}
        <S.NavButton
          color="primary"
          onClick={() => {
            setIsOpen(true);
          }}
        >
          Register
        </S.NavButton>
        <Modal
          isOpen={modalIsOpen}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            setIsOpen(false);
          }}
          style={customStyles}
        >
          <RegisterModal companyHash={companyHash} />
        </Modal>
      </S.NavBar>
      <UserLogin isOpen={loginModalIsOpen} close={closeLoginModal} />
    </S.HeaderWrapper>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Code 2(header.style.js):

```html
import styled from 'styled-components';
import LinkButton from '../../../components/LinkButton';
import { theme } from '../../../styles/theme';

export const HeaderWrapper = styled.header`
  box-sizing: border-box;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 71.5px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  padding: 80px 38px 0 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
`;

export const Logo = styled.img`
  height: 73px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
`;

export const NavBar = styled.nav`
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 5px;
  a {
    margin-left: 57px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: ${({ theme }) => theme.font.font3.new};
    font-weight: ${({ theme }) => theme.fontWeight.med_700};
  }
  a:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
`;

export const NavButton = styled(LinkButton)`
  margin-left: 52px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: ${({ theme }) => theme.font.font3.new};
  font-weight: ${({ theme }) => theme.fontWeight.med_700};
`;

export const customStyles = {
  overlay: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(30, 30, 30, .9)',
  },
  content: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '460px',
    height: '718px',
    top: '50%',
    left: '50%',
    background: '#111',
    border: `4px solid ${theme.colors.modal.border}`,
    borderRadius: '15px',
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
  },
};
```